# Easiest Way to Authenticate WP Users Using an External DB?

Tags: database, authentication

I have been looking for the best/easiest way to share users on a WP blog (in a subfolder) with the MAIN site's user database so that people do not have to register/log in on the WP blog when already registered/logged in on the main site.

It seems like this should be a fairly "common" thing, that a blog is a PART of a larger website, rather than a stand-alone website, but apparently not. I have found plenty of info on sharing users between 2+ WP installations, but the main site in my case is NOT another WP site. I had looked at a plugin called "external DB authentication" but it apparently does not work with the more recent versions of WP.

In a nutshell, I just want users on my main site to be shared with my WP blog and be able to post without having to register or login again.

Any tips/suggestions will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I can think of several ways to do it. But its quite a chunk of code. hooking onto several bits and pieces. I imagine the plugin you found is out of date, as this sort of stuff is the bread and butter of WP paid devs. Since the external db needs a whole chuck of custom bits normally to interact properly as column names won't match what anyone else uses